# Unable to populate jTable from ResultSet using two classes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

I have a class for the queries and another one for the GUI. So in my GUI class, I have these *public* members:

```
model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
table = new JTable();
```

While in the query class I have this method:

```
public void selectPassengers(int rows) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM brs.passenger";
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            String[] attributes = new String[9];

            GUI rg = new GUI();

            while (rs.next()) {
                attributes[0] = rs.getString(1);
                attributes[1] = rs.getString(2);
                attributes[2] = rs.getString(3);
                rg.model.insertRow(rg.table.getRowCount(), new Object[] {
                        attributes[0], attributes[1], attributes[2]});
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It's not inserting nor throwing an exception. It just dosen't do anything. Despite if I tried printing to the console within the `while-loop` it prints the proper data. Database and connection are fine.

Should I do something in the GUI class after executing the query?

Shortcuts are okay! I am looking for the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
table = new JTable();
```

The above code make no sense.

First you get the model from a "table" variable.

Then you create a new table. When you create a new table, the table creates a new model so it no longer references the original model.

So when you update the data in your model you are updating the old model, not the current model of the table.

The basic code should be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Now if you update the data in the model, the table and model are in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Didn't work though. I tried specifying the number of rows and columns as a parameter for DefaultTableModel(..). Nothing changes. Is my insertion code correct?

Comment: Why are you creating a new GUI in the database logic? You should be 1) creating a frame, 2) create a JTable. Add the table to a JScrollPane and then add the scrollpane to the frame. 3). Then you have a method that will insert rows of data into your table model. So first get this logic working with hard coded data. Only then do you worry about the database code.

Comment: Also, why would you create an array with 9 items and then only add 3 items to the array. Why would you then create a second array to add the data to the model? There in no need to use the insertRow() method. Just use the addRow(...) method it will automatically add the row to the end of the database.  If you need more help with the first step of loading hardcoded data into a table, then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. First you need to restructure your code to make it more logical.

Comment: Seems that I missed a lot. Haven't done the scroll pane part yet.